# Zapier Static Dropdown

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'd like to create a static combobox thanks to a custom hidden trigger.

I've seen couple examples of Zapier triggers in their repository (such as https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-trigger) but not static.

I'm using Zapier CLI and don't use the previous scripting build UI.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

If your dropdown is totally static, you can use the `choices` property outlined [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-schema/blob/master/docs/build/schema.md#fieldchoicesschema). There's a couple of different options (depending if order matters or you need labels) but the end goal is that you'll have a `choices` key with an array or object attached to it.

For example:

```js
    inputFields: [
      {
        key: 'color',
        required: true,
        choices: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
      }
    ]
```

Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Oh this is exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: One last question about it: I need to set a `perform` function as it is required but I don't need to that actually. Could you give an entire code trigger example with a static dropdown? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - your trigger needs a perform to run, even if it's only echoing static dropdowns. do you mind making a new question with what you have and the expected input/output and i can take a look?

Comment: I was going to create actually a hidden trigger with a static dropdown but actually it was not necessary as in my "main" trigger, i can add this field directly. Everything is fine, sorry to bother! Thank you!